# Deploy Silverlight OOB with ClickOnce (like LightSwitch)

Tags: silverlight, deployment, clickonce

I know the limitations of WPF clickonce deployment versus SL OOB, however, in LightSwitch apps, there is a ClickOnce Package to deploy Silverlight OOB Apps.

Is it possible to get the same behavior without using LightSwitch, say custom RIA app?

Answer (score 0):

The user can right click on the silverlight control and install the app.  If you want to force it, check in app.cs to see if the app is running out of browser, if it's not you can set the root visual to a splash screen with an install button.
http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/08/12/silverlight-out-of-browser-force-install-pattern.aspx

edit:
I don't think you can deploy SL with ClickOnce.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/59f0925b-e912-45b1-ac46-330a3f72ca76

"ClickOnce deployment is designed for smart client applications, such as WinForms or WPF apps, or console applications. AFAIK it won't work for a Silverlight app, nor will it work for WCF services, unless you include them in a client application and have it host them itself."

Comment: I would like, at least, to understand how the LightSwitch deployment model works. It looks like it's using ClickOnce although it's based in SL. I will prefer ClickOnece over OOB because I will have more control using manifests

Comment: You asked if it is possible to get the same behavior without using LightSwitch for a custom RIA app.  For SL you either right-click install or call Application.Current.Install() from the app itself.

Comment: Well, the question was: How to deploy SL apps with ClickOnce... the fact that LightSwitch implement deployment this way is just an example.

Comment: I don't think you can install a SL app with ClickOnce.

Comment: I'll ask the ClickOnce guy at Microsoft (who also leads LightSwitch) this question. I strongly suspect they have their own flavor of ClickOnce that they use.

Comment: I think people are missing the point here, or I am, silverlight is a browser plugin.  By it's nature it already has a mechanism for installing/updating itself.  Once youve browsed to it its essentially installed.  This would be akin to a flash app having click once...why?

Comment: with clickonce you will have a better control of the updating process, via App Manifests.

Comment: OOB support gives you great control.  You can check for updates at will so you could implement any process you want.  If you ever get click one working with silverlight maybe you can post it in an answer here.